# Bash: Find line similar to searchstring

Tags: bash, search

I have a csvfile like:

```
col1,col2
A,100foo
A,104foo
B,110bar
C,111bar
```

Now I have a searchstring

```
B,112
```

Which shall return line:

```
B,110bar
```

Or a searchstring

```
A,103
```

Which Shall return `A,100foo`

So I am always looking for the line 'smaller' than the searchstring.

The second column is not a number, so I cannot do math operations.

I more need something like an 'inaccurate search'.

Can I do that in Bash?
The file can be Sorte alphabetically, so I was thinking about like a 'grep-like' and the take the line before.

Comment: `agrep`? `tre-agrep`?

Comment: Does this express what you want: "first field of search string equals first field in file, second field of search string > second field of file" where `>` is lexicographically greater then

Answer (score 0):

It's not really clear how inaccurate the search is allowed to be.
Would searching all lines that begin with the same character of searchstring do?

```
str = "B,110"
grep "^${str:0:1}" csvfile
```

or are there more requirements on the format of the line?